# How to set a minimum UIPopoverController size in iOS 5?

Tags: ios5, uipopovercontroller

I am using a UIPopoverController to display properties of my ContentItems. All worked fine in iOS 4.3 using presentPopoverFromRect. Some of the ContentItem rect's are fairly large, and in iOS 5, the popover re-sizes itself to fit in the margin between the rect's edges and the screen borders. In the worst cases the popover is less than 50 pixels tall and overlays the NavigationBar. Obviously not user friendly.

I've re-written the code (latest attempt below) to detect the problem cases and give the popover a 1 pixel rect at the center point of the ContentItem. This works most of the time although I'm still reverse-engineering the behavior for some boundary cases.

However I feel I must be missing something. During the iOS 5 Beta there was some discussion of the need to specify resizing masks of the Views the popover managed - but I just find it hard to believe the behavior I'm seeing is Apple fault and not mine. Advice is appreciated.

```
- (IBAction)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    int subViewTag = sender.view.tag;
    DLog(@":tag = %d", subViewTag);

    NSString* key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", subViewTag];
    ContentItemView* contentItemView = [self.contentItemViewDict objectForKey:key];
    ContentItem* theContentItem = [contentItemView contentItem];

    ContentItemPropertiesViewController* contentPopover = [[[ContentItemPropertiesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContentItemPropertiesViewController"
                                                                                                             bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
    contentPopover.delegate             = self;
    contentPopover.theItem              = theContentItem;
    contentPopover.theView              = sender.view;
    [contentPopover setContentSizeForViewInPopover:/*k_contentItemPopoverSize*/ CGSizeMake(320, 344.0f)];
    UIPopoverController* popover        = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentPopover];
    popover.delegate                    = self;
    self.contentPopoverViewController   = popover;
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 344.0f)];
    [popover release];

    // Check to see if there's room for the popover around the edges of the object
    CGRect popoverRect = [self rectForPopover:sender.view.frame];
    if (popoverRect.origin.x   == 0 && popoverRect.origin.y    == 0 &&
        popoverRect.size.width == 0 && popoverRect.size.height == 0) {
        popoverRect = sender.view.bounds;
    }
    CGRect theRect = [sender.view convertRect:popoverRect
                                   toView:self.view];
    DLog(@"popoverRect %f, %f, %f, %f", theRect.origin.x, theRect.origin.y, theRect.size.width, theRect.size.height);
    [self.contentPopoverViewController presentPopoverFromRect:theRect 
                                                   inView:self.view  
                                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                                 animated:YES];    
}

- (CGRect)rectForPopover:(CGRect)viewRect
{
#define k_popoverPad            30.0f          // a little extra room for the popover     borders and arrow
    DLog();
    // Get the width and height the popover controller needs to fully display itself
    CGSize popoverSize      = k_contentItemPopoverSize;
    CGFloat popoverWidth    = popoverSize.width;
    CGFloat popoverHeight   = popoverSize.height;

    // Get the edges of the object's rect translated to sceneView's coordinates
    CGFloat leftEdge        = self.sceneView.frame.origin.x + viewRect.origin.x - k_popoverPad;
    CGFloat rightEdge       = leftEdge + viewRect.size.width + k_popoverPad;
    CGFloat topEdge         = self.sceneView.frame.origin.y + viewRect.origin.y - k_popoverPad;
    CGFloat bottomEdge      = topEdge + viewRect.size.height + k_popoverPad;

    // Get the bounds of the view
    CGFloat viewRightBound  = self.view.bounds.origin.x + self.view.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat viewBottomBound = self.view.bounds.origin.y + self.view.bounds.size.height;

    // Compare the "margin" between the screen bounds and object's edges
    //  to see if the popover will fit somewhere
    if (leftEdge > popoverWidth                     ||  // room on the left
        topEdge  > popoverHeight                    ||  // room at the top
        viewRightBound - rightEdge > popoverWidth   ||  // room to the right
        viewBottomBound - bottomEdge > popoverHeight) { // room at the bottom
        return CGRectZero;
    } else {
        // return a rect that is (essentially) the centerpoint of the object
        CGRect newRect = CGRectMake((rightEdge - leftEdge) / 2.0f, (bottomEdge - topEdge) / 2.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        return newRect;
    }
}
```